# Python BeautifulSoup find_all() does not work in for loop

Tags: python

```
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


directory = os.path.normpath("C:\\Users\x\\Desktop\\names.txt")
f = open(directory, 'r', encoding='utf8')
x = f.readlines()
for line in x:
    s = line.split(",")[0].replace(" ","")
    n = line.split(",")[1].replace(" ","")
    print(s + " " + n)

    res = requests.get('http://www.scopus.com/results/authorNamesList.uri?    origin=searchauthorlookup&src=al&edit=&poppUp=&basicTab=&affiliationTab=&advancedTab=&st1=' + s + '&st2=' + n + '&institute=&orcidId=&authSubject=LFSC&_authSubject=on&authSubject=HLSC&_authSubject=on&authSubject=PHSC&_authSubject=on&authSubject=SOSC&_authSubject=on&s=AUTH--LAST--NAME%28' + s + '%29+AND+AUTH--FIRST%28' + n + '%29&sdt=al&sot=al&searchId=81BECD653C7453F7BFBBB1CD8D8E5B04.wsnAw8kcdt7IPYLO0V48gA%3A220&exactSearch=off&sid=81BECD653C7453F7BFBBB1CD8D8E5B04.wsnAw8kcdt7IPYLO0V48gA%3A220')   
    content = res.content    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml').find_all('div', {'class':'dataCol2'})
    for item in soup:
        print(item.text)
        break
```

beautifulsoup.(content, 'lxml').find_all only works for the last line in x. How can i solve this?

Comment: Remove space between `.uri?` and `origin`

Comment: that's a mistake when i put the code here. normally there isn't space between them.

res.content gets different values for each itearion but beautifulsoup.find_all only works for the last iteration. I need to solve this

Comment: can you include first 2-3 lines of `names.txt?`

Comment: Aaroe, L
Abbas, Z
Abbott, G

Comment: In `res.content` there is no `div` element with `dataCol2` class when `s,n=Aaroe,LAbbas`. Check again.

Comment: s,n = Aaroe, L ... s,n = Abbas, Z

Comment: Can you share a working URL? Because for `s,n` values the URL doesn't work. It says `No authors were found`

Comment: Hey, my problem is not about scraping the website. When I do them individually, all s,n pairs work. But in for loop, .find_all function only works for the last iteration. I want to know why is this happening. Please inform me if you know the problem.

Comment: You may get what you are after more efficiently by using [the API](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/04/03/Getting-data-from-the-Scopus-API/) instead of scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working as expected:

```
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


x=["Aaroe, L","Abbas, Z","Abbott, G"]

for line in x:
    l=line.split(',')
    s=l[0].strip()
    n=l[1].strip()
    print("------------------------------------")
    print("FirstName: "+s + ", Last Name: " + n)
    res = requests.get('http://www.scopus.com/results/authorNamesList.uri?origin=searchauthorlookup&src=al&edit=&poppUp=&basicTab=&affiliationTab=&advancedTab=&st1=' + s + '&st2=' + n + '&institute=&orcidId=&authSubject=LFSC&_authSubject=on&authSubject=HLSC&_authSubject=on&authSubject=PHSC&_authSubject=on&authSubject=SOSC&_authSubject=on&s=AUTH--LAST--NAME%28' + s + '%29+AND+AUTH--FIRST%28' + n + '%29&sdt=al&sot=al&searchId=81BECD653C7453F7BFBBB1CD8D8E5B04.wsnAw8kcdt7IPYLO0V48gA%3A220&exactSearch=off&sid=81BECD653C7453F7BFBBB1CD8D8E5B04.wsnAw8kcdt7IPYLO0V48gA%3A220')   
    content = res.content    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml').find_all('div', {'class':'dataCol2'})
    for item in soup:
        print(item.text.strip())
        break
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------
FirstName: Aaroe, Last Name: L
Aarøe, Lene



Aaroe, Lene
------------------------------------
FirstName: Abbas, Last Name: Z
Abbas, Zaigham



Abbas, Z.


ABBAS, ZAIGHAM
------------------------------------
FirstName: Abbott, Last Name: G
Abbott, Albert Glenn



Abbott, A. G.


Abbott, Albert G.


Abbott, A.
```

Comment: @tech197 strip() removes all whitespaces including newline. You were not removing the `\n` which was appended to the last name.